# Executing R Codes (Dynamics Reporting) in LaTex Beamer

Tags: beamer, r

Dear all LaTex experts,

I am trying to writing some R codes and execute it in a LaTex beamer environment, or what is commonly known as dynamic reporting, but in beamer. The editor that I use for LaTex beamer is LyX. Somehow, I haven't been able to get the results correctly. The following is a simplified example.

```
\begin{Frame}[fragile]
<<>>=
2 + 2
@
\end{frame}
```

After running the codes, I got an error message. I could still get the codes to run and spit out results though. But I guess either the format or look isn't quite right. There are two error message panels. The first (upper) panel says:

```
LaTex Error: Environment Frame undefined
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
LaTex Error: Environment Frame undefined
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
```

The second (lower) panel says:

```
 \begin{Frame}
                   [fragile]
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Any thoughts? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that you've used the `Frame` environment, and not `frame`. Fix that and try again.

Comment: Sorry, that's a type. I did use frame. Thanks!

Comment: ...so that solved your problem?

Comment: @Werner I saw the same type of typo, but from WaterWood's last comment, I would suspect it was a typo only on SE and not in the original document.

Comment: @WaterWood Please edit your question and include an MWE with a complete example of compilable source code that reproduces the error. Without a complete example, answerers have to resort to guesswork to try to give you an answer ;)

Comment: Somehow I figured out and don't know why. I went to Yuhui Xie's book, Dynamic Documents with R and knitr, found an example, tried simply copying and pasting the codes, and it worked. Basically, I added an option, out.width in <<>>= like <<out.width='.6\\linewidth', size="scriptsize">>= and it worked. The size option is not necessary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it solved in the comments